# What to call someone who doesn't care whether the person he talks to understands what he says?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

For example, it's the first day at your new job and one of your colleagues is supposed to introduce you to the new working place. The person rants about everything in high speed without paying attention to whether or not you understand what he's saying.

Comment: If it weren't for OP's use of the word ***rants*** (which implies *actively hostile* behaviour), I'd just say he's talking about a ***disengaged personality*** (***semidetached***, in my idiosyncratic vernacular). But for me such a person simply doesn't care enough about whoever he's addressing to be concerned over whether his words are being understood. Of course, we could always go for the stereotypical jugular and says he's *autistic*, but I can't say I really approve of such usages even if they have some basis in fact.

Comment: Since this is about the tenth person the OP needs a label for, the issue is more likely to be with the OP rather tan everyone he has ever met.

Comment: a very bad teacher.

Answer (score 2):

***Blatherer*** or ***Blatherskite*** (thanks to Hellion for the latter variant). There are many rich expressions and words for people who talk too much, which I gather is part of your complaint because you said "rants about everything", but you also added "at high speed without paying attention to ... you ...".

So I'd say "[blatherer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blatherer)" is a good compromise. [Motormouth](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motormouth), already mentioned above, captures the rapid and excessive part, but doesn't convey the lack of empathy generally.  I think it is fair to say that [blather](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blather) usually implies long-winded, self-absorbed nonsense.

You could combine them and say "For my introduction, the motormouth just blathered on and on."

Comment: I prefer the older form, *blatherskite*, to *blatherer*.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion I too prefer *blatherskite;* it is one of those words which at first sound vulgar, but on closer inspection only appear to be so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can call him *motormouthed*, maybe *blabbermouthed*.

Answer (score 1):

An egocentric, unempathetic boor.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *unconcerned* and *blasé*.

> [blasé](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blase): having or showing a lack of excitement or interest in something because it is very familiar