# Word used to describe the act of dominating a conversation?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Someone dominates a conversation by not letting others get a word in.  I'm thinking its a combination of snow job and fillibuster (though not political in nature).

EDIT: to clarify, Not quite a long tedious speech; Speaker prompts a response but doesnt actually allow the response to be heard because the speaker begins talking again as if the response was heard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to call someone who doesn't care whether the person he talks to understands what he says?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172362/what-to-call-someone-who-doesnt-care-whether-the-person-he-talks-to-understands)

Comment: If you read the answers to this question, you may find a suitable answer, though the question is phrased differently...http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172362/what-to-call-someone-who-doesnt-care-whether-the-person-he-talks-to-understands/172414?s=4|0.1645#172414

Comment: Not sure if I can think of a word but a phrase might be suitable. The person you describe talks over other people.

Answer (score 22):

I would say "He *monopolised* the conversation"

or "Insisted on taking centre stage the whole time"

I have also heard family members say  "He was holding court" - which I think is a commonly used sarcastic reference to the way a Judge commands the attention of everyone in court .

Comment: Traditionally, "holding court" refers to what is done by a _king_, not a judge.

Comment: "holding court" has been democratized and is now an idiomatic phrase meaning "*commanding the attention*" of whoever. Kings & judges are no longer required.

Comment: @Random832: Judging was one of the primary functions of a king. Everyone else who did it was exercising delegated powers. This is why a tribunal is called a "court', because originally it was the royal court. Elected judges are very much historical outliers.

Comment: +1 - Monopolise was the word that first came to mind for me...

Comment: Interesting comments above about 'holding court' in the sense of a King  (or Queen?) - Also makes sense if you consider the wider (non-legal) meaning of the word 'court' in the case of Royalty ie in the sense of - those people who are invited to hang around with the Royals in their household - so 'holding court' would in that sense be the Monarch sitting in their throne room , attempting to be the centre of attention to the invited set of admirers/hangers-on.

Answer (score 10):

*[Monologue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/monologue)* is a good general descriptor:

> 1.1 A long, tedious speech by one person during a conversation:
>
> *ODO*

Depending on the content of the domination, *[lecture](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lecture)* might work better

> 2 A long serious speech, especially one given as a scolding or
>   reprimand:
>
> *ODO*

Comment: Not quite a long tedious speech; Speaker prompts a response but doesnt actually allow the response to be heard because the speaker begins talking again as if the response was heard.

Comment: For the sake of others who may answer, @V1GG3N you may want to edit your original post to indicate that specific detail.

Answer (score 8):

*[Harangue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/harangue)* would fit if the speaker exhibited an aggressive or critical demeanor:

> noun
>
> A lengthy and aggressive speech:

Comment: I've never heard it but this word is used in the description of the McLaughlin Group SNL skit, so it's obviously the correct answer, *right*?

Answer (score 8):

The idiom **hold forth** implies talking for a long time about a subject that interests the speaker but not necessarily the audience.

> **Hold forth**: to talk at great length; harangue
>
> *When we left, he was still holding forth on World War II.*
>
> ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hold+forth))

I first came across this phrase in Stephen King's novel *The Tommyknockers*, where it's used to describe a character drunkenly ranting about nuclear power **long** after everyone else at the party wished he'd stop.

Answer (score 7):

*[Palaver](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/palaver)* has a broad range of connotations, but it's basically a long talk:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN] 1 Prolonged and tedious fuss or discussion:

The *[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/palaver)* reveals the broad usage in various contexts:

> n.
>   1. profuse and idle talk; chatter.
>   2. persuasive talk; flattery; cajolery.
>   3. a conference or discussion, orig. one between European traders, explorers, etc., and people indigenous to a region, esp. in Africa.
>
> v.i.
>   4. to talk profusely and idly.
>   5. to confer.
>
> v.t.
>   6. to cajole or persuade.

The OP seems to be looking toward the second noun definition with connotations from verbal definition 6, and a hint of verbal definition 4. If there is a **pretense** of conversation, *palaver* is particularly useful.

---

*[Gab](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gab)* tends toward idle chatter but might work:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   Talk; chatter:

Answer (score 5):

There is ***bulldozing*** in slang.

> The act of completely dominating a conversation, whether amongst a crowd or an intimate conversation. the "Bulldozer" can be anyone, inebriated or not, so long as everyone else that has something can't, simply because the said person just talks louder to drown them out.
>
> [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bulldozing)

Answer (score 4):

[garrulous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/garrulous)

> adj.
>
> 1. Given to excessive and often trivial or rambling talk; tiresomely talkative.
> 2. Wordy and rambling: a garrulous speech.

Answer (score 2):

For me, "monopolize" comes to mind immediately and seems to the point and most appropriate without going overboard or being bullish.

There are those who seem naturally adept at monopolizing conversations by raising their voice just as someone begins to speak, interact or add information.

Answer (score 2):

**Domineering.**  "I have bookclub tonight and really hope that domineering woman is not there."

Comment: An apt answer.  Can you copy in the definition of "domineering" from your favorite dictionary (make sure to mention which dictionary!).

Answer (score 2):

*Domineering* was the first that came to mind, and is synonymous with *overbearing*.  Domineering seems to equate best with ".. dominates the .."

Answer (score 2):

*Pontification* is a good fit here

[Merriam-Webster says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pontificate):

> to speak or express opinions in a pompous or dogmatic way

*Loquacious*
Also [from Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loquacious),

> full of excessive talk :  wordy

Aaaaand one emore:

*Bloviate*

> to speak or write verbosely and windily

Answer (score 1):

[motormouth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/motormouth)

> Noun
>
> 1. someone who talks incessantly; "*I wish that motormouth would shut up*"

Comment: As your definition states, this does not necessarily describe one that **dominates** a conversation.

Comment: @DogLover I find it impossible to have a conversation with someone that talks without interruption, so I suppose you are right in that there would be no conversation to dominate.

Answer (score 1):

To address the detail you added in your edit, an insincere prompt for response is often called a *rhetorical question*. This is a question designed not to solicit information that might change the course of the conversation, but to guide the listener to ask themselves the question and formulate an answer internally. The asker might then proceed to specify the answer they believe to be best and discuss it as part of the point they're trying to reach. For this to work, the rhetorical question tends to be simple and common-sensical, ideally requiring at most trivial reasoning to answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the brief initial exchange on the phone call, Buzz commandeered the conversation in his typical **monologue** fashion.

Comment: Unfortunately, that has already been offered as an answer. It's the second most upvoted one. Excellent example sentence, though!

Answer (score -1):

The word "screed" is defined as a "long, monotonous harangue" and is similar to some of the suggestions made here.

"We tired of listening to his screed."

To "pontificate" also carries the connotation of blabbing on and on while monopolizing the conversation.

Comment: Can you add links to definitions to help the asker easily find them?

Comment: What do you mean? As in, "See Webster's"?

Comment: As in, link to an online dictionary for that word